# retrofit2 json gson как получить список объектов

Tags: android, json, retrofit

от бэкенда получаем
[image: json response]

```
private void getMasters(){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);


    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.GET_MASTERS);


    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){

                Masters masters = new Masters();

                Log.d(Constants.TAG,resp.getMessage());
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,resp.getResult());
                //Log.d(Constants.TAG,resp.getMasters().toString());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed!!!!!");
            Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

public class **ServerRequest** {

```
private String operation;
private User user;

public void setOperation(String operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}
public class **ServerResponse** {

```
private String result;
private String message;
private User user;
private Info info;

private List<Masters> masters;

private List<String> gallery;



public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public Info getInfo(){
    return info;
}

public List<Masters> getMasters() {
    return masters;
}


public List<String> getGallery() {
    return gallery;
}
```

}
Как вывести данные в лог???? нужно ли создавать класс Masters с сеттерами геттерами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pojo должны выглядеть так:

**Master.java**

```
public class Master {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    @Expose
    private String photo;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    } 
}
```

**ServerResponse.java**

```
public class ServerResponse {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private String result;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("masters")
    @Expose
    private List<Master> masters = null;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Master> getMasters() {
        return masters;
    }

    public void setMasters(List<Master> masters) {
        this.masters = masters;
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня почти также тока без сериализации. А как мне данные в лог вывести. Вообще конечная цель список создать. ReyclerView.

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov, вывод в лог у вас написан правильно